# How to show template immediately on state enter in ui-router, next when promise is resolved then show data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How to show first template and then if location promise is resolved just render it in loaded template? Even I would like to show spinner in input to inform user that data is loading. I suppose that I could do an external service that can be used directly in landingCtrl, but whether it can be done somehow through the ui-router?

```
var app = angular
  .module('myApp', [
   'ngCookies', 'ui.router'
  ])

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    .state('landing', {
        url: '/landing',
        templateUrl: 'landing.html',
        controller: 'landingCtrl',
        resolve: {
            location: [
                '$state', '$stateParams', '$q', '$window'
                , function ($state, $stateParams, $q, $window) {
                  var deferred = $q.defer();

                 $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                   function (position) {
                    deferred.resolve(position);
                 });

                 return deferred.promise;

            }]
        }
    })
}])

app.controller('landingCtrl', ['$scope', 'location', function($scope, location) {
  $scope.location = location;
}]);
```

landing.html

```
<h1>Show immediately</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="location" showspinnerwhenloading></input>
Resolved data: {{location}}
```

Comment: if you want the view to show right away then you shouldnt be using resolves. move the stuff from the resolve into your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but you could create an `abstract` state and in it's `resolve` figure out where you wanna go after, or if in your case you want to show something to the user before navigating to the main `html` you could make a concrete (not `abstract`) state and navigate to a child state in its resolve as well. It really depends on what you want to do with the main template (the one that's gonna load regardless of the location).

The implementation is gonna be something like this:

```
--main state (abstract or concrete depending on your needs)
    --child states (to which you're going to navigate to, when the parent's resolve promises return)
```

I hope I could answer your question.